# Xamarin compile issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, compilation, nuget, nuget-package

I'm experiencing alot of errors on a big project i've been working on for quite a while now.

Out of nowhere, my VS2017 doesn't recognise any xamarin references.
The project compiled flawlessly a couple of hours ago.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ien8h.png)

I get 119 errors because of this when i try to compile.

For a solution, i tried to uninstall a nuget package: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, this resulted in me not being able to install it back because i keep getting these errors when i try to install the package.

I have Xamarin.Forms installed. The bug started not being able to find certain dll files from my .net framework, i tried to solve this by giving direct references to the files, but it kept on not being able to find new dll files.

I always keep a backup on Github for reasons like this, but for some reason, the github project gives me the same bugs! It didn't when i saved it last night. This tells me my environment is screwed up, and for all i've done, i only seem to make it worse, so i don't want to mess up anything more.

Error message:

The type or namespace name 'Thickness' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'XamlCompilationAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(This continues for all 119 errors)

[New error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lduw.png)

Comment: Can you show us the actual error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your window's updates. I had the same issue a couple of hours ago and solved it with a system update

Comment: This helped somehow or atleast changed the error log, i now receive 6 new errors, i linked a picture in the original post.

Comment: @johnDoey have u tried removing the Xamarin.Forms then reinstalling it ? or just remove all references and reinstall them it helped me i did that before xamarin forms used to not be recognized and when i did that it worked

Comment: It crashed so bad i switched to my work PC instead of private PC, worked some iterations through and went back, and now it compiles again, fcking visual studio be buggy as hell.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the package folder, and let it restore, Also remove Xamarin.forms nugget then install it again

Comment: I'm afraid to uninstall anymore packages as i can't install them back.

Comment: Where do u find this 'package' folder?

Comment: I managed to uninstall and install xamarin.forms back, and reduced to 4 errors (the cannot resolve reference errors)

Comment: well the error i saw is that the package you are installing is for .net standard 2.0, try other version that is compatible on your project